# How to schedule kafka consumer properly in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use one consumer continuously read data from kafka. How should I set the scheduling options?

I have read the [`User Guide`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-tab), but I can not figure out how to set the **run schedule** and **run duration** if I need the consumer run continuously.

[image]

Comment: try `Strategy = Event driven` - if it works for kafka - use it.

Comment: @daggett I wouldn't recommend using the `Event Driven` strategy.. It is considered experimental and if Apache knew no one is using it then it would be completely removed

Comment: @BenYaakobi Then what should I use

Comment: As @BryanBende said, Timer Driven Schedule of 0 seconds would do the trick(basically the same configuration you show in your image)

Comment: Thanks. Then does the run duration option matters in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Timer Driven Run Schedule of 0 seconds means run as fast as possible continuously.

Comment: Does it mean nifi will stop and restart the consumer repeatly?

Comment: No, once the processor is started the consumer is created and connected, the run schedule is how frequently the processor will execute, and executing in this case means calling consumer.poll

Comment: Thanks, Then does the run duration option matters in this case?

Comment: The ConsumeKafka processors really shouldn't even have Run Duration, are you using GetKafka? That is an old version only meant to be used with Kafka 0.8

Comment: Yeah, I'm using kafka 0.8 and GetKafka. It confuses me that it does have this option

Comment: Run Duration is meant to be used to batch together a bunch of NiFi API operations, but it only makes sense when they are considered "side effect free" meaning the whole batch could be rolled back, I'm not sure that is really true the way GetKafka works, so I would say no reason to use that